# Running public function for each iteration in a While Loop

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to PHP and have done a few tutorials on how to code pages to run code behind. I am having trouble though figuring out why my While loop is only executing a Public Function for the first iteration through the loop. Any ideas?

```
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
$num = count($data);
$info = array("name" => "", "class" => "", "description" => "", "characteristics" => "");
        for  ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
            $info[$c] = $data[$c];
        }
        echo print_r($info);
        infoDB::getInstance()->create_record($info[0],$info[1],$info[2],$info[3]);}
```

The code above prints the $info array for each iteration of the While loop, but the create_record function only inserts the results of the first iteration into the corresponding MYSQL Database. Is there something inherent to the logic in PHP/Instantiation that means it only executes on the first iteration?

Below is the function it is calling to for reference (works correctly for the 1st iteration and then does not recur)

```
    public function create_record ($info, $class, $description, $characteristics) {
    $this->query("INSERT INTO tbl_info (toon, zeta, description, characteristics)" . " VALUES ('" . $toon . "', '" . $zeta . "', '" . $description . "', '" . $characteristics . "')");
}
```

Comment: You should call your function inside the for loop to achieve your result

Comment: `$[$c] = $data[$c];` this seems weird. You're also assigning an associative array to `$info` (i.e. using named keys), but trying to use indexed keys when you call `create_record`. It's also impossible to say if this is your whole `while` loop. Create a minimal example - remove code until you only have the `while` loop and a single `var_dump($data);` and start working from there.

Comment: edited for clarification

Comment: This is a fairly simple loop, and it is clearly working as the array prints normally. The final line is the only part of the loop that does not run with each iteration, the rest of the loop is for context

Comment: "The final line is the only part of the loop that does not run with each iteration,"...perhaps the queries are failing for some reason. Have you got error reporting and/or logging switched on? Does the database library throw exceptions when queries fail, or does it require manual checking (sometimes this is a matter of php configuration) ?

Comment: Agree with ADyson here. How do you know it's not running?

Comment: I have another page that runs a query against the PHP table, but I can also run this query directly against the database in PHPMyadmin and get the anticipated result if I replace the values. The breakdown seems to be in the way the While loop is connecting to the Instance as the {echo print_r($info)} does correctly write all rows as read in from the source

Comment: " the way the While loop is connecting to the Instance" .what do you mean by that exactly? It will still run that method. Whether that method succeeds in running the actual SQL query, we don't know. We're asking you to verify - we can't do that for you. " I can also run this query directly against the database"...how do you know precisely what query is being executed by the PHP? Are you logging the final query constructed by PHP somewhere, to prove that? BTW your queries are vulnerable to SQL injection, and also to weird syntax errors, which might be the cause of your problem

Comment: Look into using parameterised queries and prepared statements. See http://bobby-tables.com/ re SQL injection - a malicious value in the CSV could cause havoc. Also a problem could be cells containing apostrophes and that kind of thing. Parameterisation helpfully abstracts all of that away. That site has PHP/mysqli/PDO examples.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, however I don't get access to mysql logs on the server, so the best I can do to verify that everything is working by printing the array with each iteration, which as I've said displays all rows from the CSV file flawlessly, but the query in the While loop is only executing on the first iteration. It's a simple CSV file with 4 columns and 3 rows with plain text, so I have done all I have access to to ensure that it is working. I just simply keep coming back to the fact that the query is only executing the first time for some reason

Comment: Parameterisation is where I'll put my efforts. This is really just for theory and contains no valuable data, so it sounds like if I'm going to learn it I may as well learn that too

Comment: " the best I can do to verify that everything is working by printing the array", actually you could echo the final generated SQL very easily (due to the lack of parameterisation): `public function create_record ($info, $class, $description, $characteristics) {
   $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_info (toon, zeta, description, characteristics)" . " VALUES ('" . $toon . "', '" . $zeta . "', '" . $description . "', '" . $characteristics . "')";
  echo $sql;
    $this->query($sql);
}` . The SQL logs won't tell you anything anyway, they don't log every query normally.

Comment: Also I don't know if you're using mysqli or PDO, but both of those have ways to report if the "query" command fails (it will return `false`, so `$result = $this->query($sql);` will get you that response), and then you can use another method to check what the error was an echo it - check the PHP documentation for either mysqli or PDO, depending what you use. But yes hopefully parameterisation will fix it, unless you have some other issue such as unrecognised characters or something

Comment: Boom, that got it. Thanks so much! I ended up running '$parameter = $this->real_escape_string($parameter)' on each one after it is sent to 'create_record' and that took care of it. I'm still not sure what in the spreadsheet was causing the query to fail, but it was definitely something @ADyson thanks again for the assist - quite valuable

Comment: escaping the strings would certainly help if there's a problem in the data such as an a apostrophe (which would break the SQL statement). It still would be even simpler (and safer) using parameterisation, though. Glad you got it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem Solved

```
public function create_record ($info, $class, $description, $characteristics) {
$this->query("INSERT INTO tbl_info (toon, zeta, description, characteristics)" . " VALUES ('" . $toon . "', '" . $zeta . "', '" . $description . "', '" . $characteristics . "')");
```

}

Is Now

```
public function create_record ($info, $class, $description, $characteristics) {
    $name = $this->real_escape_string($name);
    $class = $this->real_escape_string($class);
    $description = $this->real_escape_string($description);
    $characteristics = $this->real_escape_string($characteristics);
$this->query("INSERT INTO tbl_info (toon, zeta, description, characteristics)" . " VALUES ('" . $toon . "', '" . $zeta . "', '" . $description . "', '" . $characteristics . "')");
```

}

The query was failing based on something it was reading in from the source spreadsheet needing to be escaped